# How do I set .mp4 image

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, image, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to set the background image of an mp4, but there doesn't seem to be any solutions that work. How do I set the image of it from the NSData I have?

Data is setup like this:

```
// Basically the JSON data gives a url to a .mp4
NSArray *preview = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.previewUrl"];
_previewData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[preview objectAtIndex:0]]];
```

Comment: Uhm.. m4a is an audio file, and cannot accept a "background image". Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: @remus Ok. When I copy it to clipboard using `"public.mpeg-4-audio"`, it pastes as an mp4 though. I can just convert it to mp4 earlier though. I updated it to say how to set mp4 image

Comment: Images are files like .jpg, .png, .bmp. Audio files are types like .mp3, .mp4 (which can also be video) and .m4a. What exactly are you doing and how/why/what are you trying to convert audio into an image?

Comment: @remus I'm trying to access the metadata of it and set the image of it. I believe you can set an .m4a's background image somehow. I'm not trying to convert anything. It's like how you can download an .mp3 and see the album art while listening to it. I'm trying to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear, you're not setting "the background image" of an audio file. You're editing the metadata of it (thanks for clarifying in the comments).

You can use a library such as [MP4Audio](https://github.com/unixpickle/MP4Audio) to do this without having to write the logic yourself:

To set the metadata for an audio file:

```
ANMovie* file = [[ANMovie alloc] initWithFile:@"test.m4a"]; // or .mp4
NSData* jpegCover = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image);
ANMetadata* metadata = [[ANMetadata alloc] init];
metadata.albumCover = [[ANMetadataImage alloc] initWithImageData:jpegCover type:ANMetadataImageTypeJPG];
[file setMovieMetadata:metadata];
[file close];
```

Comment: Can I set the initWithFile as previewData? Or do I have to convert the NSData to mp4/m4a first?

Comment: Try it? Not sure. You could also look at the source of that project and leverage it.

Comment: Using previewData as initWithFile didn't work. I don't know how to convert NSData to a file though (mp4 or m4a). I've tried looking at other questions on SO with no luck

Comment: Probably worth asking a new question for specifically that - there's not enough info from this question to really answer that either.

Comment: Ok. Just to be sure, there isn't an easy way to convert NSData into file format?

Comment: I suppose you could just write it to file (`[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];`)?

Comment: To do that, can I set up path as `NSString *path;`?

Comment: Think so. Google that method and you should find your answer.